# File Upload Extjs

Tags: extjs, file-upload

I am trying to aplly the upload file in extjs as in this example:

```
 myuploadform= new Ext.FormPanel({
            fileUpload: true,
            width: 500,
            autoHeight: true,
            bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;',
            labelWidth: 50,
            defaults: {
                anchor: '95%',
                allowBlank: false,
                msgTarget: 'side'
            },
            items:[
            {
                xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
                id: 'filedata',
                emptyText: 'Select a document to upload...',
                fieldLabel: 'File',
                buttonText: 'Browse'
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Upload',
                handler: function(){
                    if(myuploadform.getForm().isValid()){
                        form_action=1;
                        myuploadform.getForm().submit({
                            url: 'handleupload.php',
                            waitMsg: 'Uploading file...',
                            success: function(form,action){
                                msg('Success', 'Processed file on the server');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }]
        })
```

When i run it i see it tries to upload the file and nothing happends(it never finishes);

Now as i understand the handleupload.php should process the uploaded file.

I have tryed aplying it as in this eaxmple: [file upload using EXT JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514937/file-upload-using-ext-js/7260325#7260325)

but I cant seem to make it work, what should be exactly in the php file?

ty.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the SDk download of uploading a file with a PHP backend (PHP code included). Look under /examples/form/file-upload.html.

That should have everything you need.

Comment: cant find the php part. thats the only part i am missing, can you please copy the code for the php server side

Comment: It's called `file-upload.php`.

Comment: I created an handleupload.php with the code from the example, and In the console i get: "Uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: ..."

Comment: There's a fully working example, don't really know what else to say.